# Type missing when try Spring framework quickstart

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning Spring framework and build my first Spring application according to the quickstart on http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/. I use the maven dependency to add the respective libraries, and add the three java file. However, I can't compile Application.java because of following error at Line 1:

```
The type org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanNameGenerator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

And the whole project looks like this:

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help me.

UPDATED:
Application.java
[image]

Comment: For starters, you should update your Java version to 1.7 or 1.8. That might not resolve this issue, but it isn't helping.

Comment: @chrylis Thank you for advice. I do this but the problem remains.

Comment: Post the POM, and as text, not an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will have to import the `org.springframework.beans.factory.support` package in your `pom.xml` file so that it can be available at compile time.

Comment: Thank you! It works. When I add `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
 <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>` to pom.xml, it compiles successfully.